# Fragment inflating onCreateView parameters

Tags: android

```
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta , container , false);
```

We use this line of code for inflating. Despite read documentary , i didn't understand what is the second and third parameters function is ? What is the root in this situation and what happen if i change third to true ?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,android.view.ViewGroup,android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Thanks but documentary was this , and i didn't understand logic in container and false , sorry. As my understanding container(root) is Activities layout but why i give false for attach(third)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Layout Inflater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxVeFwtIpVc)

The video should give you a good explanation of what is done and why it is done.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout XML file some of the attributes relate to the parent container. Anything that starts with layout_*. The container, or parent in some cases, is needed to resolve those values. You can see this with things like layout_margin. If you don't give the inflater a parent you won't have any margins. But if you wrap your layout in another container like a frame layout it works. That's because it's able to resolve layout_margin using the frame layout. I'm not completely sure about the attach to parent boolean. I always get Exceptions when I set it to true.